# Mysql - return all results from table A and selectively join with table B

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables:

default:

```
+----+--------+
| id | colour |
+----+--------+
| 1  | red    |
| 2  | green  |
| 3  | yellow |
+----+--------+
```

custom:

```
+--------+--------------+---------+
| linkId | customcolour | ownerId |
+--------+--------------+---------+
| 1      | bright red   | 1       |
| 2      | garden green | 2       |
+--------+--------------+---------+
```

I want to return everything from the default table and then get any associated customcolours (via the linkId). The query I am using is:

```
SELECT a.colour, b.customcolour 
FROM default a 
LEFT JOIN custom b ON a.id = b.linkId
WHERE (b.ownerId IS NULL OR b.ownerId = 1) 
GROUP BY a.id ORDER BY a.colur
```

However when I join to the custom table it will not select custom linkId 2 because the ownerId is not 1 nor NULL. Is there a way to return the row default.id = 2 and just set customercolour as NULL, without adding it to the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your WHERE criteria into the join

```
SELECT a.colour, b.customcolour 
FROM default a 
LEFT JOIN custom b ON a.id = b.linkId AND (b.ownerId IS NULL OR b.ownerId = 1)
GROUP BY a.id ORDER BY a.colur
```

Comment: brilliant thanks, could you briefly explain why I need the WHERE into the JOIN?

Comment: Because it's a `left join` and not an `inner join`.

Comment: @xylar - When you want to include nulls (i.e., when you're using outer joins), you need to specify what gets nulled out in the join -  I want all the things in Table A joined to all the things that exist in table B (for whatever criteria is in the join) and the where filters things after the join.   In your query, b.ownerId IS NULL OR b.ownerId = 1 is part of the criteria for what is null and what's not, not what rows to choose.